# Getting fetch result from the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

What am I doing wrong? price and article do not render on the first qr scan but from the second, third... I am guessing that it got something to do with asynchronous code, but I can not see what i need to do... Can someone help me please?   Tnx in advance!

```
export default class Qr extends Component {
  state = {    
    price: [],
    article: [],
  };

  qrCodeOnReadHandler = ({ data }) => {
    let price = this.state.price;
    let article = this.state.article;

  fetch(data)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => [
      console.log(json),
      article.push(json[0]),
      price.push(parseInt(json[4]))
    ]);

  console.log(price);
  console.log(article);
 };

render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         <View style={styles.price}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Proizvod: {this.state.article}</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.price}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Cena: {this.state.price}</Text>
         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you call qrCodeOnReadHandler ?

Comment: I cleaned up the code so it would not be there too much unnecessary code.

Comment: I wouldn't alter those price and article arrays like that. Since they're part of `this.state`, always update them with `this.setState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly modifying the state. That's a no no. You should call setState instead

```js
export default class Qr extends Component {
  state = {    
    price: [],
    article: [],
  };

  qrCodeOnReadHandler = ({ data }) => {

  fetch(data)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => [
      console.log(json),
      this.setState({
        article: [...this.state.article, json[0]],
        price: [...this.state.price, json[4]],
      })
    ]);
 };

render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         <View style={styles.price}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Proizvod: {this.state.article}</Text>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.price}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Cena: {this.state.price}</Text>
         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... actually that was it... It renders like charm now, from the first scan. Thanks a lot ageoff!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!